# WordPress two-level filters on getting custom taxonomy terms

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have a Custom Post Type Called `movie` and I have two taxonomies `genre` and `quality`  associated with that. Now I need to get/filter all terms if:

```
genre = 'action'
AND
quality = 'HD'
```

Using this code I am able to get all terms which has genre term of action

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
                    'genre' => 'action',
                    'hide_empty' => false,
                    ) );
foreach ($terms as $term){
    echo $term->name;
}
```

but as I said I need to get all `action` terms which are also `HD`!
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can able to filter by tax_query:

```
   $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'movie',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'genre',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array( 'add genre terms name')
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'quality',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array( 'add quality terms name', 'add quality terms name' ),
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Jahid but is this returning Terms?

Comment: you will gets movies post after filters

Comment: Oh No, I need the Terms only, No need to get the CTPs